# Is there a compilation of AP CSP scores by curriculum?

Tags: secondary-education, grading, ap-cs-principles

The overall distribution of scores for the first AP CSP (Computer Science Principles) exam was recently [released](https://www.reddit.com/r/APStudents/comments/6jvibw/ap_csp_score_distribution/), and I'm wondering how much is described there about students' performance when their classrooms used Code.org vs. Beauty and Joy vs. Mobile vs. all the other flavors out there.

Is there a site/blog post that compiles/reports the scores by curriculum?

I know it's a bit early to ask, but maybe this will prompt the creation of such a resource :)

Comment: That is probably best asked at the [AP Computer Science](https://apcommunity.collegeboard.org/group/apcompsci) site, where you need to create an account. They have a regular message board that is divided up into interest groups and you can be part of as many as you like.

Comment: If you could collect that information, that would make a great publication/resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for UTeach CSP and as far as I understand, the College Board released has results to endorsed providers from 2017-2018 (meaning projects like CS50 and CodeHS aren't included because they were approved after the beginning of the year). They are not planning to release the scores themselves, but leaving it up to providers to share. Below are links to provider score publications that I have seen. There may be information for BJC and PLTW, but I haven't seen them.

UTeach: [UTeach Computer Science Principles and Underrepresented Students](https://medium.com/@uteachinstitute/uteach-computer-science-principles-and-underrepresented-students-f1c445df638d)

Code.org: [73% of Code.org students passed the AP exam!](https://medium.com/@codeorg/73-of-code-org-students-passed-the-ap-exam-187cd65b9a88)

Mobile CSP: [78% of Mobile CSP Students Passed AP Exam](http://blog.mobile-csp.org/2017/09/23/78-of-mobile-csp-students-passed-ap-exam/)

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Educators! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the pages you linked here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Both UTeach and Code.org have released their scores. 83% of UTeach students passed, 73% of code.org students passed. UTeach also published the results of females and underrepresented minority groups. In all categories, a higher percentage of UTeach students passed than the national averages.

I've been trying to find released data from the others and I can't.